# Extract a value from within a nested key python

Tags: python, key, python-3.6

I need to extract out a specific value from within a nested key in python 
for example from the below I want to extract out the Start from the key Params

```
{'Key': 'Params', 'Value': `'{"Shut":false,"Remove":false,"SnapshotRequired":false,"Start":"Never","End":"Never"}'}
```

This is as far as I have got

```
            for tag in i["Tags"]:
            if 'Params' in tag['Key']:
```

then I can get the value but this is the whole string.

Comment: You need to convert the `tag['Value']` string into a dictionary. Is it JSON? using eval could be a security issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dict.get(key)` method to get a value of the key you specify in `get()`, where `dict` is variable which stores your dictionary.

Also you can use `dict[key]`. It gives the same result.

In your case, for example, `dict['Key']` will return 'Params',
`dict['Value']` will return nested dictionary.

Comment: There is a difference between `[]` and `get`. While the first raises an error for missing keys the latter just returns `None`. Thus, "It gives the same result." is not always correct.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after fixing an issue in the string, an extra '`' you can simply make dict(string) to make it a valid python dict, which then accepts nested dicts as values.
also have in mine that "false" is not a valid python type, so you would have to make it a string or convert to python format which is False with the capital F

and finally do:
variable['Value']['Start']

```
test = dict({'Key': 'Params', 'Value': {"Shut":False,"Remove":False,"SnapshotRequired":False,"Start":"Never","End":"Never"}})
test['Value']['Start']
```